# Rollback installation based on a condition

Tags: c#, installation, windows-installer, multiple-login

While unistalling the application normally if more than one user is logged in the system, it would show a message box

[image]

if the user hits continue, the uinstallation happens but might be with errors. I've a project installer, in which I want to end the installation process if more than one users are logged in. So I wrote this condition in the Before_UnInstall event:

```
if(Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer").Count()==1)
{
        //do uinstall
}

else
{
       //do not do unistall
}
```

My question was how do I stop the uninstall event from being fired, in the else part?

**Possible Change**

based on Alexey's answer I thought I would check the distinct owners of the process. I found how to find the owner of a process using WMI from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338534/how-do-i-find-out-what-user-owns-what-process-programmatically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not do it yourself: Windows Installer will take care of the files locked by other processes. Additionally, it is legitimate for a user to have *several explorer processes*, so your code will refuse to uninstall in such case, yet only one user is logged on. And I doubt you can detect processes from other users, unless you run this code elevated.

What you really want to check is whether the application you uninstall is running under any user account. If other users of the computer do not have your application running, it is usually safe to proceed.

Comment: +1 for the promptness :) Yes, I when I check the process count from admin account, it works. I've edited the code, so that it may work in the scenario you refered. But i am not able to test it. Please tell in which condition a user owns multiple explorer.exe. I tried to create new task "explorer.exe", but no process was made.

Comment: I found how a user can have more than one explorer.exe. It occurs when you pass arguments to explorer.exe. I will make necessary changes in my code and get back to you :)

Comment: You should not count processes, it is error-prone. You should better detect there are other users logged on. And even with one desktop session it is possible to run processes under different user account. Why do you want to prevent users from uninstalling your app after all? Do you have any *real* problems with uninstall?

Comment: To have several explorer processes, you can configure the shell to run folder windows in another process. In this case your desktop with taskbar will live in one process, and any folder windows will live in another process.

Comment: Actually. It is a Silverlight OutOfBrowser app. By default when you do the installation, the shortcut will be placed only on the current user's(admin) desktop. So I move the shortcut to public desktop to make it available for all from code in my installer. When multiple users are logged in during the uninstallation, some exception occurs., and thus wont execute the command to remove the icon from Public desktop. So after the unistallation, the non functional .lnk will be still there!

Comment: Thus you have to find the root cause why the exception occurs. Does it work as expected where only one user is logged on? Does it work correctly if another user uninstalls the application? Additionally you should place the shortcut to public desktop with MSI, then it will take care of removing it.

Comment: with a single user logged in it works good. By MSI, you mean the project installer right? i does moving of the shortcut in that only.

Comment: Yes, I mean the setup project itself, or Windows Installer database. You wrote you *moved* the shortcut to public desktop from code. And I mean you should not use *code* to do it but you should place it right away to public desktop. Set [`ALLUSERS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367559.aspx) property to `2`, and then [`DesktopFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368276.aspx) will point to public desktop. In this case, MSI would remove the shortcut, and no code to remove it is required.

Comment: but in OOB installation we are specifying to create the application shortcut. the desktop shortcut will be current users desktop.

Comment: @user841923 I am confused… If need the shortcut on public desktop, you should create it there, doing so during installation is a good idea. It's better than creating shortcut on current user's desktop and then moving it to public desktop. Alternatively, if you don't want to change the way it is created, you can change the way it is removed: Add an entry into RemoveFile table and associate it with a component, preferably which installs the shortcut, and mark it to be removed on uninstall only.